# How to allow two authentication access to one route in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have one route with protect by admin authentication(midleware). but I want employer auth can access this route too. how can I do that in contructor.

```
    public function __construct()
    {
            $this->middleware('auth:admin');
           // $this->middleware('auth:employer');
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Seprate by `|`

```
 $this->middleware('auth:admin|employer');
```

Comment: error : Auth guard [admin|employer] is not defined.

Comment: What if with  `auth:admin,employer`

Comment: it say : Auth guard [ employer] is not defined.